# JoinableQueue's join() function causes my program to hang

Tags: python, multiprocessing, queue

I have a program, which uses multiprocesses to execute functions from an external hardware library. The communication between the multiprocess and my program happens with `JoinableQueue()`.
A part of the code looks like this:

```
# Main Code
queue_cmd.put("do_something")
queue_cmd.join() # here is my problem

# multiprocess 
task = queue_cmd.get()
if task == "do_something":
  external_class.do_something()
queue_cmd.task_done()
```

Note: `external_class` is the external hardware library.
This library sometimes crashes and the line `queue_cmd.task_done()` never gets executed. As a result, my main program hangs indefinitely in the `queue_cmd.join()` part, waiting for the `queue_cmd.task_done()` to be called. Unfortunately, there is no timeout parameter for the join() function.

How can I wait for the element in the `JoinableQueue` to be processed, but also deal with the event of my multiprocess terminating (due to the crash in the `do_something()` function)?
Ideally, the join function would have a timeout parameter (`.join(timeout=30)`), which I could use to restart the multiprocess - but it does not.

Comment: So putting a try/catch around the call to `do_something()` will not work?

Answer (score 0):

You can always wrap a blocking function on another thread:

```py
queue_cmd.put("do_something")
t = Thread(target=queue_cmd.join)
t.start()

# implement a timeout
start = datetime.now()
timeout = 10  # seconds
while t.is_alive() and (datetime.now() - start).seconds < timeout:
    # do something else
    # waiting for the join or timeout
if t.is_alive():
    # kill the subprocess that failed
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach here is to start the "crashable" module in (yet) another process:

**Main code**

```
queue_cmd.put("do_something")
queue_cmd.join()
```

**Multiprocess**  (You can now move this to a thread)

```
task = queue_cmd.get()
if task == "do_something":
  subprocess.run(["python", "pleasedontcrash.py"])
queue_cmd.task_done()
```

**pleasedontcrash.py**

```
external_class.do_something()
```

As shown, I'd do it using `subprocess`. If you need to pass parameters (which you could with `subprocess` using pipes or arguments), it's easier to use `multiprocessing`.